# page jumps with <a href> adding websites randomly to links

Tags: html, href, blogger, page-jump

I'm trying to make page jumps on a page in blogger, using:

```
<a href="#Test">Test</a>
```

for the source and

```
<a name="Test"></a>
```

for the target.

And this is all fine and dandy except when I switch from html mode to compose mode...and then back to html mode. When this happens it triggers the above lines to all of a sudden turn in to these two lines:

```
 <a href="https://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=6870619294109194114#Test">Test</a>

 <a href="https://www.blogger.com/null" name="Test"></a>
```

Where the blogID site is a login for blogger.com and the null site just gives an error message.

It's quite annoying and, while I could just manually delete these added web addresses each time, I am hoping someone out there has a solution that will stop this from happening as i have a lot of jumps and will constantly be updating the page.

Does anyone know why this addition happens and how to stop it?!

Comment: This addition happens because Blogger is a horrible piece of poorly designed software. Ignore me, though; I’m just being bitter. In all seriousness, the best way to stop it from happening is to stop using Blogger.

Comment: Instead of using `<a name="Test">` (which is obsolete), you can give the element you’re trying to link to an `id` attribute of `Test`. That should help with the `null` issue, but as for the link’s expansion, you really would just have to use literally anything else. Heck, go with WordPress or something.

Comment: The only way to prevent that from happening is to do the HTML part first and then use compose mode and never switch back to HTML mode. :)

Comment: The Blogger Editor is the worst part about it. I myself just never use the compose mode at all because the code blogger puts out is horrible (just like the templates) this is why I just write all of my code myself, be it the template or the post. But as suggested, it should work without a problem if you change the name to an actual ID.

Answer (score 1):

Actually sometimes This problem occurs because this link https://www.blogger.com/null generated automatically and cause re-routing of the error page.
To solve this problem, enter the Html tab for the post and then look for this link and then remove it from the code, then publish your post immediately in Html Tab.
and you should not return to compose tab to avoid automatic generation of this  link  again.
you can see [Demo](http://translate.google.com/translate?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.condaianllkhir.com%2F2014%2F11%2Fhide-show-multiple-divs.html%23.VLv0UyxGQ3g&langpair=auto%7Cen&hl=en)

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar proplem when working with this blog [Workscheduling](http://workschedulingapps.blogspot.com/). the solution is to edit the link separately and then test it before pasting.